# Set on which a holomorphic function is bounded is simply connected

Tags: complex-analysis

I came across this problem and couldn't figure it out:

*Let $U$ be a simply connected domain, and let $f:U\to\Bbb{C}$ be holomorphic on $U$. For $c>0$ define $V_c:=\{z:|f(z)|<c\}$. Show that every domain in $V_c$ is simply connected.*

It's equivalent to showing that every connectivity component of $V_c$ is simply connected. (Because $V_c$ isn't necessarily connected)

Comment: Suppose you had a component $W$ of $V_c$ that isn't simply connected. What are some characterisations of simply connected domains that could be useful here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $W$ be a connected component of $V_c$. Suppose $W$ weren't simply connected. Then there would be a $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}\setminus W$, and a simple closed piecewise continuous differentiable curve $\gamma$ in $W$ with winding number $n(\gamma,z_0) = 1$. Since $U$ is simply connected, we have $D = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : n(\gamma,z) = 1\} \subset U$. Since $\partial D = \operatorname{Tr} \gamma$ is a compact subset of $V_c$, the maximum modulus theorem asserts that $D\subset V_c$. But $D$ is connected - it is homeomorphic to the unit disk - and $D\cap W \neq \varnothing$, thus the set $W\cup D$ is connected. Since $W$ is a component of $V_c$, it follows that $D\subset W$. But then we have $z_0 \in W$, contradicting the assumption.